# Bazel test for self written tensorflow c++ code is passing every test regardless of expected value

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel

I'm using bazel to build my own tensorflow c++ code. I'm currently stuck with the writing of unit tests, because the test are passing for every test I wrote, regardless of the expected values. E.g I'm checking the dimensions of a tensor, which should be 4, but if I say that the expected value is 5 it still passes. And that behaviour is truth for every test I wrote.

I feel like it's a problem with the bazel BUILD file I wrote or maybe even tensorflow. Currently I'm using a cc_library for some helper functions. And tf_cc_test for the unit test. I also used tf_cc_binary and cc_binary for the helper functions, but then I'm getting a undefined reference error for one function which was declared in the header file and defined in the source file.

This is the layout of my folders and files:

```
dl_super_resolution
   |
   |-src
   |  |-dl_model_helper.cpp 
   |
   |-include
   |  |-dl_model_helper.h
   |
   |-test
   |  |-dl_model_helper_unit_test.cpp
```

The #includes in dl_model_helper.cpp and dl_model_helper_unit_test.cpp are as follows:

```
#include <dl_model_helper.h>
```

This is how the BUILD file looks like currently:

```
load("@org_tensorflow//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_cc_test")

cc_library(
    name = "dl_super_resolution_lib",
    srcs = [
        "src/dl_model_helper.cpp",
        "src/dummy.cpp",
    ],
    hdrs = ["include/dl_model_helper.h"],
    data = glob(["images/**"]),
    includes = [
        "include",
        "src",
    ],
    strip_include_prefix = "include",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so",
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/cc:cc_ops",
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/cc:client_session",
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:framework",
        "@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
    ],
)

tf_cc_test(
    name = "dl_super_resolution_tests",
    srcs = glob(["test/*.cpp"]),
    deps = [
        ":dl_super_resolution_lib",
        "@googletest//:gtest_main",
    ],
)
```

I'm expecting to the unit tests to fail if they actually should fail. So far it is always passing. If more information is needed I can share my repository as well.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to get it to run by adding this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

This should not be required when running the unit test with "bazel test" I think. But this solves the problem.